# Outlook add-in mysteriously changing message body

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I am experiencing strange behavior in my Outlook Addin. When replying to a message, it opens a form region and calls the following:

```
private void MyAddin_FormRegionShowing(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    Outlook.MailItem mail = this.OutlookItem as Outlook.MailItem;
    string body = mail.Body;
    // arbitrary code can follow
}
```

These two little lines for some reason change the Body of the original message! It adds a header like this to the original message:

```
From: xxx
Sent: xxx
To: xxx
Subject: xxx
```

If I execute the same two lines later (e.g., as a response to a user click), it doesn't have this affect, but my addin needs to see the body when the message opens, not just as a response to a user click. How can I access the Body without changing any message? (I'm using Office 2013)

Comment: Simply reading the Body property won't alter the message. However, since this is a reply the Body of the source email that's being replied to will differ from the reply message, in that of course the latter will include the header text.

Comment: Of course the reply includes the new header text. The strange thing is that when I send or cancel the reply and then go back to the orginal in the mailbox, it has now mysteriously changed! Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, that's just weird! Are you sure you don't have any other code running that could be editing the message body? Do you have anti-virus software with Outlook integration?? Otherwise I'm stumped

Comment: Yeah, but I found that if I make the code run on the first occurrence of the form's Paint routine rather than the FormRegionShowing, the problem goes away. Strange....